# Inserting multiple values in database codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I want to insert multiple rows in the database on one click if row is checked using multiple checkbox
[image]

Here is my code=>
1)Controller: `guard.php`
(Here I take a array of list of student id's and pass them one by one to the another function get_leave_data which take id of a student and return more information about the student from another table `leave_application`).

```
public function students_out(){
    $request=$this->input->post('approve_leave_status');
    if($request=="OUT"){
    $check_list_out[]=$_POST['check_list_out'];
    if(!empty($check_list_out)){
          foreach ($check_list_out as $check_list_id) {
            $student_data=$this->get_leave_data($check_list_id);
            $this->insert_student_outside($student_data);
          }
          $this->load->helper('url');
          $this->load->view('view_guard');
    }
}else{
     $this->load->helper('url');
     $this->load->view('view_guard');
}

} `

 public function get_leave_data($id){
 $this->load->model('model_guard');
 $data=$this->model_guard->get_data($id);
 return $data;
}

public function insert_student_outside($std_data){
  $this->load->model('model_guard');
  $data=$this->model_guard->insert_student_out($std_data);
 return $data;
}
```

2)Model: model_guard.php
(The functions `get_data()` and `get_data2()` return more informations about student and function `insert_student_out()` insert the student to the `student_outside table`)

```
public function get_data($id){
    $this->db->select('leave_id,leave_from_roll_no,leave_student_name,leave_going_to,leave_from_date,leave_till_date,leave_hostel_no,leave_status');
    $this->db->from('leave_application');
    $this->db->where('leave_id',$id[0]);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    $data1=$query->result();
    $data2=$this->get_data2($data1);
    $final_array=array_merge($data1,$data2);
    return $final_array;
    }

    public function get_data2($array){
    foreach ($array as $key) {
    $roll_no=$key->leave_from_roll_no;
    }
    $this->db->select('student_year,student_semester,student_parent_email');
    $this->db->from('students');
    $this->db->where('student_roll_no',$roll_no);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    $data=$query->result();
    return $data;
    }

    public function insert_student_out($std_data){
    $roll_no=$std_data[0]->leave_from_roll_no;
    $id=$std_data[0]->leave_id;
    $date_out=date('Y-m-d');
    $inside_date=NULL;
    $date_allowed=$std_data[0]->leave_till_date;
    $array=array(
    'outside_id'=>$id,
    'outside_roll_no'=>$roll_no,
    'outside_date_out'=>$date_out,
    'outside_date_in'=>$inside_date,
    'outside_date_allowed'=>$date_allowed
    );
    if($this->db->insert('students_outside',$array)){
        return true;
    }else{
        false;
    }


    }
```

Comment: I am not seeing you call your model file in your controllel

Comment: What's the actual problem.

Comment: according to @saty you should load your model and then call it from your controller.

Comment: i have updated the post. I accidentally forgot to add two functions in guard.php

Comment: now what error you're getting?

Comment: actually if I tick 2 or more rows then only 1 row is added to the student_outside table. I want to add multiple rows to the table based on tick marks.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to insert batch_array using codeignator

the right syntax to using batch_array is:-

```
$array=array(
    'coloum_name'=>$id,
    'coloum_name'=>$roll_no,
    'coloum_name'=>$date_out,
    'coloum_name'=>$inside_date,
    'coloum_name'=>$date_allowed
    );

if($this->db->insert_batch('students_outside',$array)){
        return true;
    }else{
        false;
    }
```

you can read manual [insert_batch](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert) here

Comment: I m getting errors using insert_batch
Severity: Warning

Message: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php

Line Number: 1114

Comment: @electron i have edit my post the column name is your table column name

Answer (score 0):

ok, i am assuming that in `$std_data` you have more than one record.then in your model's `insert_student_out()` function try this-

```
public function insert_student_out($std_data){

 foreach($std_data as $row){
       $roll_no=$row->leave_from_roll_no;
       $id=$row->leave_id;
       $date_out=date('Y-m-d');
       $inside_date=NULL;
       $date_allowed=$row->leave_till_date;
       $array=array(
              'outside_id'=>$id,
              'outside_roll_no'=>$roll_no,
              'outside_date_out'=>$date_out,
              'outside_date_in'=>$inside_date,
              'outside_date_allowed'=>$date_allowed);

       $this->db->insert('students_outside',$array);

  }
}
```

Comment: $std_data is an object not an array of object